# Python: Running nested loop, 2D moving window, in Parallel

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I work with topographic data. For one particular problem, I have written a function in Python which uses a moving window of a particular size to zip through a matrix (grid of elevations). Then I have to perform an analysis on this window and set the cell at the center of the window a resulting value.

My final output is a matrix the same size as my original matrix which has been altered according to my analysis. This problem takes 11 hours to run on a small area, so I thought parallelizing the inner loop would accelerate things. *Alternatively, there may be a clever vectorization solution too...*

See my function below, `DEM` is a 2D numpy array, `w` is the size of the window.

```
def RMSH_det(DEM, w):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import signal
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #create an empty array to store result
    rms = DEM*np.nan

#    nw=(w*2)**2
#    x = np.arange(0,nw)

    for i in np.arange(w+1,nrows-w):


        for j in np.arange(w+1,ncols-w):

            d1 = np.int64(np.arange(i-w,i+w))
            d2 = np.int64(np.arange(j-w,j+w))

            win = DEM[d1[0]:d1[-1],d2[0]:d2[-1]]

            if np.max(np.isnan(win)) == 1:
                rms[i,j] = np.nan

            else:
                win = signal.detrend(win, type = 'linear')
                z = np.reshape(win,-1)
                nz = np.size(z)
                rootms = np.sqrt(1 / (nz - 1) * np.sum((z-np.mean(z))**2))
                rms[i,j] = rootms


    return(rms)
```

I have scoured SO/SE for solutions to my question and come across many examples of nested for loops and trying to run them in parallel. I've struggled to adapt my code to match the examples and would appreciate some help. A solution to this problem would help me work with several other moving window functions I have.

Thus far, I have moved the inner loop into it's own function, which can be called from within the outer loop:

```
def inLoop(i, w, DEM,rms,ncols):
        for j in np.arange(w+1,ncols-w):

            d1 = np.int64(np.arange(i-w,i+w))
            d2 = np.int64(np.arange(j-w,j+w))

            win = DEM[d1[0]:d1[-1],d2[0]:d2[-1]]

            if np.max(np.isnan(win)) == 1:
                rms[i,j] = np.nan

            else:
                win = signal.detrend(win, type = 'linear')
                z = np.reshape(win,-1)
                nz = np.size(z)
                rootms = np.sqrt(1 / (nz - 1) * np.sum((z-np.mean(z))**2))
                rms[i,j] = rootms


        return(rms)
```

But I wasn't sure of the correct way of coding the call to Pool with the necessary variables that need to be input into the inner loop. See the outerloop below:

```
 for i in np.arange(w+1,nrows-w):
        number_of_workers = 8

        with Pool(number_of_workers) as p:
            #call the pool
            p.starmap(inLoop, [i, w, DEM, rms, ncols])
```

Remaining questions:

- Can this code even be optimized by parallelizing?
- How do I successfully store the result of a parallelized nested-for loop?

Comment: Would you mind to be more specific ( failed to post an MCVE here -- irreproducible ) ? What are your use-case explicit values of **`[nrows, ncols], dem.dtype, dem.flags`** and **`w`** and what are your target run-times, in **`[hours]`**, that you aim to get your solution designed?

Comment: `[nrows, ncols] =` 1355, 1165
`dem.dtype` = float32
`dem.flags =  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False`
`w = 10`

Currently it takes 11 hours to run, I would like to see a result in under six or faster.

Comment: Is a Numba solution also alowed? It would be possible to do (with a little rewrite)  in less than 10s.

Comment: @max9111 would you mind check the remarks about the performance hints in the code below and adapt your proposed code not to devastate the original data in DEM ( via assignments "through" the np.view()-only ) and only after this is corrected - would you mind to test it on updated DEM-scales?  13k1 x 11k4 x 4B float32 dtype? Thanks for your kind re-considerations and numba-compiled scipy.signal.detrend() trick. **All the respect for doing this, Sir.**

Comment: There was another error in isnan(win). np.nan==np.nan is always false....

Comment: Yikes, any solution at hand?

Comment: This was corrected yesterday. I have also added a faster but less precise solution using normal equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A solution using Numba

In some cases this is very easy to do, if all functions which you use are supported. In your code `win = signal.detrend(win, type = 'linear')` is the part you have to implement in Numba, because this function isn't supported.

**Implementing detrend in Numba**

If you look at the [source-code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L2464-L2543) of detrend, and extract the relevant parts for your problem, it may look like this:

```
@nb.njit()
def detrend(w):
    Npts=w.shape[0]
    A=np.empty((Npts,2),dtype=w.dtype)
    for i in range(Npts):
        A[i,0]=1.*(i+1) / Npts
        A[i,1]=1.

    coef, resids, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, w.T)
    out=w.T- np.dot(A, coef)
    return out.T
```

I also implemented a faster solution for `np.max(np.isnan(win)) == 1`

```
@nb.njit()
def isnan(win):
    for i in range(win.shape[0]):
        for j in range(win.shape[1]):
            if np.isnan(win[i,j]):
                return True
    return False
```

**Main function**

As I used Numba here, the parallelization is very simple, just a prange on the outer loop and

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def RMSH_det_nb(DEM, w):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #create an empty array to store result
    rms = DEM*np.nan

    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):
        for j in range(w+1,ncols-w):
            win = DEM[i-w:i+w-1,j-w:j+w-1]

            if isnan(win):
                rms[i,j] = np.nan
            else:
                win = detrend(win)
                z = win.flatten()
                nz = z.size
                rootms = np.sqrt(1 / (nz - 1) * np.sum((z-np.mean(z))**2))
                rms[i,j] = rootms

    return rms
```

**Timings (small example)**

```
w = 10
DEM=np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float32)

res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
res2=RMSH_det_nb(DEM, w)
print(np.allclose(res1,res2,equal_nan=True))
#True

%timeit res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
#1.59 s ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res2=RMSH_det_nb(DEM, w) #approx. 55 times faster
#29 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Timings for larger arrays**

```
w = 10
DEM=np.random.rand(1355, 1165).astype(np.float32)
%timeit res2=RMSH_det_nb(DEM, w)
#6.63 s ± 21.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**[Edit] Implemenation using normal Equations**

[Overdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)

This method has a **lower numerical precision**. Although this solution is quite a lot faster.

```
@nb.njit()
def isnan(win):
    for i in range(win.shape[0]):
        for j in range(win.shape[1]):
            if win[i,j]==np.nan:
                return True
    return False

@nb.njit()
def detrend(w):
    Npts=w.shape[0]
    A=np.empty((Npts,2),dtype=w.dtype)
    for i in range(Npts):
        A[i,0]=1.*(i+1) / Npts
        A[i,1]=1.

    coef, resids, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, w.T)
    out=w.T- np.dot(A, coef)
    return out.T

@nb.njit()
def detrend_2(w,T1,A):
    T2=np.dot(A.T,w.T)
    coef=np.linalg.solve(T1,T2)

    out=w.T- np.dot(A, coef)

    return out.T

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def RMSH_det_nb_normal_eq(DEM,w):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #create an empty array to store result
    rms = DEM*np.nan

    Npts=w*2-1
    A=np.empty((Npts,2),dtype=DEM.dtype)
    for i in range(Npts):
        A[i,0]=1.*(i+1) / Npts
        A[i,1]=1.

    T1=np.dot(A.T,A)

    nz = Npts**2
    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):
        for j in range(w+1,ncols-w):
            win = DEM[i-w:i+w-1,j-w:j+w-1]

            if isnan(win):
                rms[i,j] = np.nan
            else:
                win = detrend_2(win,T1,A)
                rootms = np.sqrt(1 / (nz - 1) * np.sum((win-np.mean(win))**2))
                rms[i,j] = rootms

    return rms
```

**Timings**

```
w = 10
DEM=np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float32)

res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
res2=RMSH_det_nb(DEM, w)
print(np.allclose(res1,res2,equal_nan=True))
#True

%timeit res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
#1.59 s ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res2=RMSH_det_nb_normal_eq(DEM,w)
#7.97 ms ± 89.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Optimized solution using normal equations**

Temporary arrays are reused to avoid costly memory allocations and a custom implementation for matrix multiplication is used. This is only recommendable for very small matrices, in most other cases np.dot (sgeemm) will be a lot faster.

```
@nb.njit()
def matmult_2(A,B,out):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        acc1=nb.float32(0)
        acc2=nb.float32(0)
        for k in range(B.shape[0]):
            acc1+=A[0,k]*B[k,j]
            acc2+=A[1,k]*B[k,j]
        out[0,j]=acc1
        out[1,j]=acc2
    return out

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def matmult_mod(A,B,w,out):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        for i in range(A.shape[0]):
            acc=nb.float32(0)
            acc+=A[i,0]*B[0,j]+A[i,1]*B[1,j]
            out[j,i]=acc-w[j,i]
    return out

@nb.njit()
def detrend_2_opt(w,T1,A,Tempvar_1,Tempvar_2):
    T2=matmult_2(A.T,w.T,Tempvar_1)
    coef=np.linalg.solve(T1,T2)
    return matmult_mod(A, coef,w,Tempvar_2)

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def RMSH_det_nb_normal_eq_opt(DEM,w):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #create an empty array to store result
    rms = DEM*np.nan

    Npts=w*2-1
    A=np.empty((Npts,2),dtype=DEM.dtype)
    for i in range(Npts):
        A[i,0]=1.*(i+1) / Npts
        A[i,1]=1.

    T1=np.dot(A.T,A)

    nz = Npts**2
    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):
        Tempvar_1=np.empty((2,Npts),dtype=DEM.dtype)
        Tempvar_2=np.empty((Npts,Npts),dtype=DEM.dtype)
        for j in range(w+1,ncols-w):
            win = DEM[i-w:i+w-1,j-w:j+w-1]

            if isnan(win):
                rms[i,j] = np.nan
            else:
                win = detrend_2_opt(win,T1,A,Tempvar_1,Tempvar_2)
                rootms = np.sqrt(1 / (nz - 1) * np.sum((win-np.mean(win))**2))
                rms[i,j] = rootms

    return rms
```

**Timings**

```
w = 10
DEM=np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float32)

res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
res2=RMSH_det_nb_normal_eq_opt(DEM, w)
print(np.allclose(res1,res2,equal_nan=True))
#True

%timeit res1=RMSH_det(DEM, w)
#1.59 s ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res2=RMSH_det_nb_normal_eq_opt(DEM,w)
#4.66 ms ± 87.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Timings for isnan**

This function is a completely other implementation. It is much faster if a NaN is quite at the beginning of the array, but anyway even if not there is some speedup. I benchmarked it with small arrays (approx. window size) and a large size suggested by @user3666197.

```
case_1=np.full((20,20),np.nan)
case_2=np.full((20,20),0.)
case_2[10,10]=np.nan
case_3=np.full((20,20),0.)

case_4 = np.full( ( int( 1E4 ), int( 1E4 ) ),np.nan)
case_5 = np.ones( ( int( 1E4 ), int( 1E4 ) ) )

%timeit np.any(np.isnan(case_1))
%timeit np.any(np.isnan(case_2))
%timeit np.any(np.isnan(case_3))
%timeit np.any(np.isnan(case_4))
%timeit np.any(np.isnan(case_5))
#2.75 µs ± 73.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#2.75 µs ± 46.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#2.76 µs ± 32.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#81.3 ms ± 2.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
#86.7 ms ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit isnan(case_1)
%timeit isnan(case_2)
%timeit isnan(case_3)
%timeit isnan(case_4)
%timeit isnan(case_5)
#244 ns ± 5.02 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
#357 ns ± 1.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
#475 ns ± 9.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
#235 ns ± 0.933 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
#58.8 ms ± 2.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: are you sure the code is correct? The SLOC **`win = DEM[i-w:i+w-1,j-w:j+w-1]`** assigns the `win` to be a **`np.view()`** into a region of the original `DEM` where the modifications from `win = signal.detrend(win, type = 'linear')` **actually DESTROY the original DATA in `DEM` + the rest is being processed on such already damaged / devastated `DEM`-data ...** was this an intention of the O/P ? **`+1`** for implementing the `.detrend()`-method for `numba`

Comment: @user3666197 No in the dtrend  is another array (out) allocated. Therefor after the line `win = detrend(win)` win points to another memory area. Maybe I should rename the variables to make this more clear.

Comment: pre-allocation (one time costs) of a "working-kernel-win" would improve the performance - ~1M + times executed for [1k3,1k1]-demo, **~150M+ times executed for [13k1,11k4]-real-DEM,** so worth cleaning all the overheads possible out :o)

Comment: Thank you @max9111, for this solution. I'm trying to implement it at the moment. First a question, do I need to define the detrend and max functions in separate files from the main RMSH function? Or can I call a single function with those sub-functions defined within?

Comment: @max9111 I was able to successfully implement your solution and on my test grid (1165 x 1355) it took 7 seconds and appears to have replicated the results of the original algorithm. Is the root of the speed increase parrallelizing the outer loop?

Comment: @morrismc They do not have to be in the same file, if they are in another file you have to call them like import myfile myfile.dtrend(...). There should be also quite a lot more tweaks to gain performance. np.linalg.lstsq maybe reimplemented or the the whole detrend from the very basics for moving windows. But this is quite some work, with uncertain results.

Comment: @morrismc Please check the updates! I had a severe bug in my initial implementation (running out of bounds). No, most of the speed up comes from calling the BLAS algorithms from compiled code, and also from compiling the rest of the code. You can check this with parallel=False

Comment: Ok, I have confirmed that the results of these two techniques are within the error I'm concerned about of each other. The order of magnitude increase is spectacular! I greatly appreciate the help provided by this community!

Comment: @max9111 I haven't encountered any issues but will update my code to match any changes

Comment: Final question, is there a way to print out a time remaining or update a waitbar from within the nb.prange loop?

Comment: @morrismc Sorry I don't know a way how to do this.

Comment: @morrismc **On process-updates:** if this makes some sense for your large-scale computing application, you may include a ZeroMQ-based reporting to some central progress-monitor, showing all the respective scientific-workflow progress reported in some reasonable spaced intervals ( Each ~1% progress reported? Each ~5% progress reported? ) to be shown on a central [ Distributed Computing Progress Panel ]. Pretty doable with reasonable add-on costs. Did the same for a large-scale Machine Learning Infrastructure for fast and massively parallel ( on ML-Model-Jobs scale ) Model-prototyping pipelines.

Comment: @max9111 **Would you mind** to post a comment with measured results on what acceleration was achieved on **`numba.njit( def isnan(win) )`**-ed code, when benchmarked against the native `numpy.any( numpy.isnan( win ) )` - to have a fair-level benchmark? Best use the `win = np.ones( ( int( 1E4 ), int( 1E4 ) ) )` for this to let indeed burn the oil - smoke on :o)

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *This problem **takes 11 hours** to run on a small area,...*  <sub>stay tuned, we can and **we'll get under 20 [min]** !!</sub>

given due explanations were provided, for which I thank the O/P author:

```
# DEM.shape = [nrows, ncols] = [ 1355, 1165 ]
# DEM.dtype = float32 
#    .flags = C_CONTIGUOUS    : True
#             F_CONTIGUOUS    : False
#             OWNDATA         : True
#             WRITEABLE       : True
#             ALIGNED         : True
#             WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#             UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

I tried to review the code and setup a mock-up of a bit more efficient code, before moving into putting all popular and ready-to-use **`numpy + numba`** steroids in, and the interim **`numpy`-only result works**
 on a sample of `[100,100]` DEM-grid for **about `~ 6 [s]`** at the said kernel window width **`w = 10`**

The same, for `[200,200]` DEM-grid, takes under **`~ 36 [s]`** - obviously, the scaling is **`~ O( N^2 )`**

The same, for **`[1000,1000]`** DEM-grid, took under **`~ 1077 [s] ~ 17.6 [min]` wow !**

A field `.jit` trial on `[1000,1000]` DEM-grid is currently under the test and will update the post once finished + once the **`numba.jit()`** code will enjoy to run the further accelerated results

---

### So far, quite promising, isn't it?

If you [@morrismc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508596/morrismc) test your as-is code now, on a `[100,100]`-matrix, we can already guess the achieved range of the principal **speedup**, even before running tests are completed.

```
>>> pass;    import numpy as np
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch; clk = Stopwatch()
>>>
>>> size =  100; demF32 = np.random.random( ( size, size ) ).astype( np.float32 ); resF32 = demF32.copy(); clk.start(); _ = RMSH_det( demF32, 10, resF32 ); t = clk.stop(); print( "{1:>13d} [us]\nNumOf_np.nan-s was {0:d}".format( _, t ) )
      6492192 [us]
NumOf_np.nan-s was 0

>>> size =  200; demF32 = np.random.random( ( size, size ) ).astype( np.float32 ); resF32 = demF32.copy(); clk.start(); _ = RMSH_det( demF32, 10, resF32 ); t = clk.stop(); print( "{1:>13d} [us]\nNumOf_np.nan-s was {0:d}".format( _, t ) )
     35650629 [us]
NumOf_np.nan-s was 0

>>> size = 1000; demF32 = np.random.random( ( size, size ) ).astype( np.float32 ); resF32 = demF32.copy(); clk.start(); _ = RMSH_det( demF32, 10, resF32 ); t = clk.stop(); print( "{1:>13d} [us]\nNumOf_np.nan-s was {0:d}".format( _, t ) )
   1058702889 [us]
NumOf_np.nan-s was 0
```

All this on `scipy` 1.2.1, thus without the benefits from 1.3.1 possible further speedups

---

### A `numba.jit()` LLVM-compiled code. Ooops, slower ?

**`numba.jit()`**-acceleration has shown about **`200 [ms]` worse** runtime on `[100,100]` DEM-grid, with signature having been specified ( so no ad-hoc analysis costs were accrued here ) and `nogil = True` ( '0.43.1+0.g8dabe7abe.dirty' not being the most recent, yet )

Guess there is nothing more to gain here, without moving the game into compiled **`Cython`** territories, yet having about tens of minutes instead of tens of hours, the Alea Iacta Est - **just the `numpy`** smart-vectorised code rulez!

---

### EPILOGUE :

If the original algorithm was correct (and some doubts were left in the source-code for any further improvement work), **any attempt to run some other form of  `[PARALLEL]` code-execution-flow will not help here** ( kernel-windows[w,w] are very-small and non-contiguous areas of the DEM-grid memory-layout, memory-I/O costs are dominant part of the run-time budget here, and some nicer indexing may improve the cache-line re-use, yet the overall efforts are well beyond the budget, as **the target of going down from `~ 11 [hrs]` to about `~ 6 [hrs]` was more than successfully met** with about **`~ 20 [min]`** runtimes achievable for `[1300,1100]` float32 DEM-grids

The code was left as-is ( non-PEP-8 ), because of all the add-on didactic value for the **`[DOC.me], [TEST.me]`** and **`[PERF.me]`** phases of QA, so all kind PEP-isto-evangelisators do bear with the O/P author's view onto a full-scree-width layout left, so as to allow to understand **WHY** and to improve the code, which with stripped-off-comments would lose her/his way forwards in improving the code performance further on. Thx.

```
@jit( [ "int32( float32[:,:], int32, float32[:,:] )", ], nogil    = True )                  # numba.__version__ '0.43.1+0.g8dabe7abe.dirty'
def RMSH_det_jit( DEMf32, w, rmsRESULTf32 ):                            # pre-allocate rmsRESULTf32[:,:] externally
    #import numpy as np
    #from scipy import signal
    #
    # [nrows, ncols] = np.shape( DEM )                                  # avoid ~ [ 1355, 1165 ]
    #                                                                   # DEM.dtype = float32 
    #                                                                   #    .flags = C_CONTIGUOUS    : True
    #                                                                   #             F_CONTIGUOUS    : False
    #                                                                   #             OWNDATA         : True
    #                                                                   #             WRITEABLE       : True
    #                                                                   #             ALIGNED         : True
    #                                                                   #             WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
    #                                                                   #             UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
    #
    rmsRESULTf32[:,:] = np.nan                                          #        .STO[:,:] np.nan-s, using in-place assignment into the by-ref passed, externally pre-allocated np.ndarray
    dtdWIN            = np.ones( ( 2 * w - 1,                           #        .ALLOC once, re-use 1M+ times
                                   2 * w - 1 ) )
    a_div_by_nz_minus1 = 1. / ( dtdWIN.size - 1  )                      #        .SET float CONST with about a ~1M+ re-use
    a_num_of_NaNs      = 0                                              #        .SET i4 bonus value, ret'd as a side-effect of the signature ... 
    # rms = DEM*np.nan                                                  # avoid ( pre-alloc rmsRESULTf32 ) externally create and pass a right-sized, empty array to store all results
    # nw  = ( w * 2 )**2
    # x   = np.arange( 0, nw )

    #                        11..1344
    #or     i in np.arange( w+1,           nrows-w ):                   # w ~ 10 -> [11:1344, 11:1154]
    for     i in np.arange( w+1, DEMf32.shape[0]-w ):                   #         ??? never touches DEM-row/column[0]?? or off-by-one indexing error ???
        fromI = i - w                                                   #        .UPD ALAP
        tillI = i + w - 1                                               #        .UPD ALAP upper bound index excluded ( this is how a code in [ np.arange(...)[0]:np.arange(...)[-1] ] works )
        #                    11..1154
        #or j in np.arange( w+1,           ncols-w ):
        for j in np.arange( w+1, DEMf32.shape[1]-w ):
            fromJ = j - w                                               #        .UPD ALAP
            tillJ = j + w - 1                                           #        .UPD ALAP upper bound index excluded ( this is how a code in [ np.arange(...)[0]:np.arange(...)[-1] ] works )
            #                       1..1334:21..1354                    #         ??? never touches first/last DEM-row/column??
            # d1 = np.int64( np.arange( i-w, i+w ) )                    # AVOID: 1M+ times allocated, yet never consumed, but their edge values
            # d2 = np.int64( np.arange( j-w, j+w ) )                    # AVOID: 1M+ times allocated, yet never consumed, but their edge values

            # win = DEM[ d1[0]:d1[-1],                                  # AVOID: while a .view-only, no need to 1M+ times instantiate a "kernel"-win(dow] ( this will create a np.view into the original DEM, not a copy ! )
            #            d2[0]:d2[-1]                                   # ?.or.?   NOT a .view-only, but a new .copy() instantiated, so as to call .detrend() w/o in-place modifying DEMf32 ???
            #            ]                                              # ?.or.?   NOT a .view-only, but a new .copy() instantiated, so as to call .detrend() w/o in-place modifying DEMf32 ???
            dtdWIN[:,:] = DEMf32[fromI:tillI, fromJ:tillJ]              #          NOT a .view-only, but a     .copy() re-populated into a just once and only once pre-allocated dtdWIN, via an in-place copy
            #f np.max( np.isnan(    win ) ) == 1:                       # AVOID: 1M+ times full-range scan, while any first np.nan decides the game and no need to scan "the rest"
            if np.any( np.isnan( dtdWIN ) ):                            #        "density" of np.nan-s determine, if this is a good idea to pre-store
               a_num_of_NaNs += 1                                       # .INC
               continue                                                 #        .NOP/LOOP from here, already pre-stored np.nan-s for this case
               # rms[i,j] = np.nan                                      # DUP ( already stored in initialisation ... )
            else:
               #in    = signal.detrend(    win, type = 'linear' )       # REALLY?: in-place modification of DEM-matrix ???
               dtdWIN = signal.detrend( dtdWIN, type = 'linear'   )     #    in scipy-v1.3.1+ can mod in-place,   overwrite_data = True ) # REMOVE OLS-fit-linear trend
               dtdWIN = signal.detrend( dtdWIN, type = 'constant' )     #    in scipy-v1.3.1+ can mod in-place,   overwrite_data = True ) # REMOVE mean
               #z  = np.reshape( win, -1 )                              # AVOID:~1M+ re-counting constant value, known from w directly
               #nz = np.size( z )                                       # AVOID:~1M+ re-counting constant value, known from w directly
               #rootms    = np.sqrt( 1 / ( nz - 1 ) * np.sum( ( z - np.mean( z ) )**2 ) )
               #rms[i,j]  = rootms
               rmsRESULTf32[i,j] = np.sqrt( a_div_by_nz_minus1          # .STO a "scaled"
                                          * np.dot(   dtdWIN,
                                                      dtdWIN.T
                                                      ).sum()
                                          # np.sum( ( dtdWIN            #         SUM of
                                          #       # - dtdWIN.mean()     #               mean-removed ( ALREADY done via scipy.signal.detrend( 'const' ) above )
                                          #           )**2              #               SQUARES
                                          #         )
                                            )                           #      ROOT
    return( a_num_of_NaNs )                                             # ret i4
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am currently trying to run through this code and realized that the 1165 x 1365 example ran in ~7 minutes with my existing code. When I run the same DEM through the code example you provided, it runs in ~6.7 minutes. So not an order or magnitude improvement.  I can provide the DEM file if that's helpful.

Comment: I just tried your code on a random 1000 x 1000 grid and the function ran significantly faster (4.1 minutes). Not sure why the speedup, perhaps do to the shape of my original matrix.

Also, the full grid that took 11 hours was 13078 x 11437.

Comment: Ok, 13k1 x 11k4 x 4B starts to enter the zone of Divide-and-Conquer for faster processing and using compiled-code - the composite of Cython + OpenMP tooling will become handy, yet the cache-line coherence grows to increase its power of impacts ( or adverse effects, if working in a cache-line re-use bad-aligned ordering ). With split-tiles and 8 CPU-cores, a better than target performance is definitely achievable, yet the CPU/RAM memory-I/O channels represent the principal ceiling.

Comment: So we are back to the discussion about parralelization and how to accomplish this with the existing code or modifying the existing code. Any insights on this are welcome.

Comment: @morrismc see the advice of re-compiling a **.detrend()**-substitude, which speeds-up further the proposed 'numba.jit'-way. A higher-level OpenMP based parallelism with Cython-ised code is a next level, if needed, to explicitly split the DEM-into-tiles, so as to efficiently harness all CPU-cores ( remember, RAM / CPU memory-I/O bottleneck will still remain to govern the performance ceiling ) without the single-threaded, GIL-lock-stepped ( yes, pure SEQUENCE, re-[SERIALISED]-code execution. For details on OpenMP / Cython https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html#compiling

Comment: The GIL is released in njit(). OpenMP is one possible threading backend which is used by Numba. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/threading-layer.html Basically Cython (nogil) translates to C/C++ Numba (njit mode) translates to LLVM-IR, quite like Clang (both use the LLVM backend to get machine code). If you find quite a low-level performance issue, it does even make sense to compare with the more common frontend Clang, which is another translator (C-> LLVM-IR). It's straight forward to get 2+ speedup with a less stable algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system

Comment: I have added a faster, but less precise algorithm the (13k,11k) example now runs in about 100s.

Comment: @max9111 ~ 100 [s] for [13k1,11k4] of float32 is indeed nice. Respect ~!~ ( for the numba code, AFAIRC all called functions ought have been compiled either, this was in numba requirements since ever, wasn't it? )