# Numba compatible equivalent of numpy.gradient

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am currently working to optimize a series of functions for a problem I'm working on. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507565/python-running-nested-loop-2d-moving-window-in-parallel?noredirect=1#comment103416735_58507565) to my original question that helped me accelerate my code.

I'm now trying to use the Numba solution suggested there for another, similar function. In this case, I am creating another moving window with nested for loops that loops through all of the rows and columns of a numpy matrix containing elevation data. The particular function I'm working on at the moment requires a call to `numpy.gradient`

`[fx, fy] = np.gradient(DEM, cellsize, cellsize)`

However, when I try to implement my function using Numba, I run into an issue with `gradient`.

`TypingError: Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.gradient' or unsupported use of the function.`

I couldn't find an appropriate replacement for the functionality of the Gradient function via searching online. I thought this community could help.  I greatly appreciate any insights or advice you can provide.

If you require more context or information I can provide that as well.

After Max9111's comment, I decided to build two different functions, one that took the gradient out of the Numba function.
`first fuction`

```
def DCE_preprocess(DEM, cellsize, w):

    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #initiate an empty array same size as dem
    rms = DEM*np.nan
#    rms = np.float32(rms)

#    #compute the directional cosines
    [fx, fy] = np.gradient(DEM, cellsize, cellsize)


    grad = np.sqrt(fx**2 + fy**2)
    asp = np.arctan2(fy, fx)



    grad=np.pi/2-np.arctan(grad) #normal of steepest slope
    asp[asp<np.pi]=asp[asp<np.pi]+[np.pi/2]
    asp[asp<0]=asp[asp<0]+[2*np.pi]

    #spherical to cartesian conversion
    r = 1
    cy = r * np.cos(grad) * np.sin(asp)
    cx = r * np.cos(grad) * np.cos(asp)
    cz = r * np.sin(grad)

    return(cx,cy,cz)
```

returns input for the `second function`

```
eps = np.finfo(float).eps
```

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def DC_eig_par(DEM,w,cx,cy,cz,eps):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)
#
#    #initiate an empty array same size as dem
    rms = DEM*np.nan

    #Compute RMS cycling through the DEM
    nw=(w*2)**2
    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):


        for j in range(w+1,(ncols-w)):
            d1=np.int64(np.linspace(i-w,i+w,11))
            d2=np.int64(np.linspace(j-w,j+w,11))

            tempx = cx[d1[0]:d1[-1],d2[0]:d2[-1]]

            tx=np.reshape(tempx,-1)
            tempy = cy[d1[0]:d1[-1],d2[0]:d2[-1]]
            ty=np.reshape(tempy,-1)
            tempz = cz[d1[0]:d1[-1],d2[0]:d2[-1]]
            tz=np.reshape(tempz,-1)

            if np.isnan(np.concatenate((tx,ty,tz))) == 0:
                T=np.array([[np.sum(tx**2), np.sum(tx*ty), np.sum(tx*tz)],
                             [np.sum(ty*tx), np.sum(ty**2), np.sum(ty*tz)], 
                             [np.sum(tz*tx), np.sum(tz*ty), np.sum(tz**2)]])


                [Te,_] = np.linalg.eig(T) # this step is a bit different from the matlab version b/c np.eig outputs two values.
                l = (Te/nw)
                l[l<eps] = 0
                rms[i,j] = 1/np.log(l[0]/l[1])


            else:
                rms[i,j] = np.nan

    return(rms)
```

I now get the following error:

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (int64, Literal[int](0))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at U:\GHP\Projects\NSF - Morris Landslides\Code\Developmemnt\Wavelets\DC_eig_par.py (58)
[2] During: typing of static-get-item at U:\GHP\Projects\NSF - Morris Landslides\Code\Developmemnt\Wavelets\DC_eig_par.py (58)
```

Which appears to be an issue with the slicing I'm trying to do using tempx/y/z

Comment: Here is the source to the numpy gradient function: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L801-L1140

Comment: This is quite straight forward to implement `fy[i,j]=(DEM[i,j+1]-DEM[i,j-1])/(2*cellsize)` in the middle and `fy[i,0]=(DEM[i,j+1]-DEM[i,0])/(2*cellsize)` at the beginning and `fy[i,-1]=(DEM[i,-1]-DEM[i,-2])/(2*cellsize)` at the other border. fx is just the transposed operation.

Comment: @max9111, I'm assuming that the ``i`` and ``j`` in your psuedocode are references to indices in nested for loops to go through all of the elements in a matrix.

Comment: @max9111 I removed gradient and several other functions from my initial Numba function call and use them to create the inputs for a new function (see above). I no longer have the issue with np.gradient; however, I now seem to have trouble from the slicing of a matrix... Any insights?

Comment: It's hard to follow your question and I was unable to understand what exactly you want. Do you want a numba-version of `np.gradient`? What is `DC_eig_par` supposed to be and how does it related to the question regarding `np.gradient`. Why does it have to be parallel? Is the original solution too slow? What is the original solution? Where is numba applied? I see no `nb.jit` (or similar) decorators. It would be really helpful if you could make your question more succinct and if you ask **one specific question** instead of several (including some implicit) questions.

Comment: @MSeifert To answer your questions, I made a mistake in modifying my original query. Initially, I wanted to see if there was a Numba compatible version of np.gradient. However, I decided to remove the call to `np.gradient` from my code entirely and move it into a separate function that pre-processed my inputs and delivered those inputs to a second function.
1) `DC_eig_par` ideally takes a matrix of elevations and uses a moving kernel window to calculate the Directional Cosine Eigen vectors for that window. 
2) I hope to run this code in Parallel because the pre-existing code is so slow.

Comment: 3) Here's a link to the original non-parallelized code [link](https://github.com/morrismc/wavelets/blob/master/DC_eigen.py)
4) I have edited the code block above to show the `@nb.njit` call