# Numba fails when using moving kernel window: TypingError, definition error

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, jit, numba

I'm working on a project that requires me to build a series of functions that use a moving kernel window to manipulate elevation data stored in a matrix.

My original question of how to optimize two nested for loops was answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507565/python-running-nested-loop-2d-moving-window-in-parallel?noredirect=1#comment103416735_58507565). The solution involved parallelizing my code with **Numba**. When I tried to adapt another moving kernel window function to numba, I ran into an issue with `numpy.gradient` which is currently unsupported by numba. So I broke my function in two: **A)** a preprocessing function not in Numba and **B)** the main function written in Numba. I am now trying to get the function run with numba to work properly. I continue to get an error (shown below) and am now pretty frustrated after weeks scouring the stack exchange and internet for a solution.

Functions are shown below:

`first function`

```
def DCE_preprocess(DEM, cellsize, w):

    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)

    #initiate an empty array same size as dem
    rms = DEM*np.nan
#    rms = np.float32(rms)

#    #compute the directional cosines
    [fx, fy] = np.gradient(DEM, cellsize, cellsize)


    grad = np.sqrt(fx**2 + fy**2)
    asp = np.arctan2(fy, fx)



    grad=np.pi/2-np.arctan(grad) #normal of steepest slope
    asp[asp<np.pi]=asp[asp<np.pi]+[np.pi/2]
    asp[asp<0]=asp[asp<0]+[2*np.pi]

    #spherical to cartesian conversion
    r = 1
    cy = r * np.cos(grad) * np.sin(asp)
    cx = r * np.cos(grad) * np.cos(asp)
    cz = r * np.sin(grad)

    return(cx,cy,cz)
```

which returns the input for my second function:
`second function`

`eps = np.finfo(float).eps`

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def DC_eig_par(DEM,w,cx,cy,cz,eps):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)
#
#    #initiate an empty array same size as dem
    rms = DEM*np.nan
    rms.astype(np.float32)

    #cycling through the DEM
    nw=(w*2)**2

    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):


        for j in range(w+1,(ncols-w)):

            d1=nb.int32(np.linspace(i-w,i+w,11))
            d2=nb.int32(np.linspace(j-w,j+w,11))

            tempx = cx[(d1[0]):(d1[-1]),(d2[0]):(d2[-1])]
            tx=np.reshape(tempx,-1)
            

            tempy = cy[(d1[0]):(d1[-1]),(d2[0]):(d2[-1])]
            ty=np.reshape(tempy,-1)
            
            tempz = np.empty([10,10], dtype = np.float32)
            tempz = cz[(d1[0]):(d1[-1]),(d2[0]):(d2[-1])]
            tz=np.reshape(tempz,-1)

            if np.max(np.isnan(np.concatenate((tx,ty,tz)))) == 0:
                T=np.array([[np.sum(tx**2), np.sum(tx*ty), np.sum(tx*tz)],
                             [np.sum(ty*tx), np.sum(ty**2), np.sum(ty*tz)], 
                             [np.sum(tz*tx), np.sum(tz*ty), np.sum(tz**2)]])
                
                
                [Te,_] = np.linalg.eig(T) # this step is a bit different from the matlab version b/c np.eig outputs two values.
                l = (Te/nw)
                l[l<eps] = 0
                rms[i,j] = 1/np.log(l[0]/l[1])
                
                
            else:
                rms[i,j] = np.nan

    return(rms)
```

The second function now gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-af12df87ecaa>", line 8, in <module>
    rp = DC_eig_par(DEM, w,cx,cy,cz,eps)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 351, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 318, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (int32, Literal[int](0))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at U:\GHP\Projects\NSF - Morris Landslides\Code\Developmemnt\Wavelets\DC_eig_par.py (40)
[2] During: typing of static-get-item at U:\GHP\Projects\NSF - Morris Landslides\Code\Developmemnt\Wavelets\DC_eig_par.py (40)
```

The code fails on line `40` which is `tempx = cx[(d1[0]):(d1[-1]),(d2[0]):(d2[-1])]`. I'm not sure what's going on. I've made sure that all variables are of a consistent type throughout, or so I thought. Any insights or help anyone could offer as to a way to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Running similar functions in parallel cuts operation from 6 minutes for a 1165 x 1355 matrix to seconds. I hope to have a similar speedup with this function.
Thanks so much

Comment: Numba can only handle types that are supported by numba. What is the type of members in cx?

Comment: cx, cy, and cz are float32 ```np.ndarray```

Comment: I have already corrected this weird slicing in the answer before. If cx is a 2d array you can replace the first four lines in the inner loop with `tx = cx[i-w:i+w,j-w:j+w]`.

Comment: @max9111, I have now replaced the slicing per your suggestion with:
`tempx = cx[i-w:i+w,j-w:j+w]  tx=np.reshape(tempx,-1)`
The code now fails on line 41, the call to reshape. With a much longer traceback than I can post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully resolve this issue after a lot of trial and error and digging more into the TraceBack. My new function reads as follows:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def DC_eig_par(DEM,w,cx,cy,cz,eps):
    [nrows, ncols] = np.shape(DEM)
#
#    #initiate an empty array same size as dem
    rms = DEM*np.nan
    rms.astype(np.float32)

    #Compute RMS cycling through the DEM
    nw=(w*2)**2

    for i in nb.prange(w+1,nrows-w):


        for j in range(w+1,(ncols-w)):
#            d1=np.int16(np.linspace(i-w,i+w,11))
#            d2=np.int16(np.linspace(j-w,j+w,11))

            tempx = cx[i-w:i+w,j-w:j+w]
            tx = tempx.flatten()



            tempy = cy[i-w:i+w,j-w:j+w]
            ty = tempy.flatten()


            tempz = cz[i-w:i+w,j-w:j+w]
            tz = tempz.flatten()



            if (np.isnan(np.concatenate((tx,ty,tz)))).sum() == 0:
                T=np.array([[np.sum(tx**2), np.sum(tx*ty), np.sum(tx*tz)],
                             [np.sum(ty*tx), np.sum(ty**2), np.sum(ty*tz)], 
                             [np.sum(tz*tx), np.sum(tz*ty), np.sum(tz**2)]])


                [Te,_] = np.linalg.eig(T) # this step is a bit different from the matlab version b/c np.eig outputs two values.
                l = (Te/nw)
                l[l<eps] = 0
                rms[i,j] = 1/np.log(l[0]/l[1])


            else:
                rms[i,j] = np.nan

    return(rms)
```

Major changes are that I:

1. Eliminated the call to `reshape` and instead used `tempx.flatten`
2. The call to `max` within my if statement was changed to `.sum()`

The code now runs like a charm. In 6 seconds as compared with the 6 minutes the non-parallelized code takes to run.